# How can I catch a Side-By-Side (SxS) manifest load error without crashing on startup?

Tags: c#, c++, com, sxs

I have a C++ application which uses controls contained in a managed (C#) library.

The controls are activated using [Registry-Free COM Interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1h056h(v=vs.100).aspx) (SxS activation).
If the managed library is missing, the application shuts down immediately with a generic and unhelpful dialog: 
("Unable to start program X", "This Application has failed to start... blah...blah")
What I would like to do, is catch the error and present the user with my own (hopefully more helpful) message.  Better yet, I would like to allow the application to continue loading and just disable the few dialogs that actually use the managed library and its controls (only a tiny fraction of the main application uses this library).
Unfortunately, the error from the SxS loader seems to happen before any of my code gets a crack at handling it.
Can I catch and handle these errors?  If so, how?
Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that the error is generated by the system loader before it even tries to enter your code.  Is there a way of marking the libraries as optional in the manifest and testing for them after startup?

Comment: Exactly.
"Is there a way of marking the libraries as optional in the manifest...?"
I wish I knew!  :)
If that's possible, I'd like to know how, but in my reading I haven't seen a way.

Comment: you can't ship the DLLs you depend on with your product?

Comment: You'd have to activate the manifest yourself instead of leaving it up to the loader to do it for you.  http://www.mazecomputer.com/sxs/help/sxsapi2.htm

Comment: Joseph - If only it were that easy.  Our installation/update procedure (if you can call it that) is too chaotic to guarantee that the dll is there and is the right version.

Comment: Hans - I'll look into that.  Thanks.

Comment: Manually loading the Activation Context was the ticket.  Hans - you should post this as an answer.